# How to use Oauth from Rstudio server?

Tags: r, linux, facebook, amazon-ec2, oauth

I am monitoring a pair of facebook pages using the Rfacebook library from my laptop with win & Rstudio.

I am doing this via a loop that runs the getPage function: 'getPage(id, token=fbOauth)' for each of the pages I am monitoring, pauses for some time, and then does it all over again.

This works perfectly fine on a win/osx machine with Rstudio, as long as the Oauth object has been made through the browser, before initializing the loop.

The procedure for creating the oauth object is that:

1. Enter app relevant info into the fbOAuth function
2. Manually typing enter in the console
3. Browser window appears, and then the Oauth object in R has been made

However, my plan is to run the code from Rstudio server on a EC2 linux instance, which makes it impossible to open a browser window before intializing the loop.

I was thinking of exporting the environment from Rstudio on my desktop computer after the Oauth object has been made, and then somehow loading it into the environment of my EC2 instance running Rstudio Server.

Is there a way of doing this? And/or is there other ways to make the Oauth object generated by the Rfacebook package when using linux?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the Oauth object in the environment from R in an .Rdata file and loading it from the server instance, solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To do so,
  First I did the usual fbOAuth function on my Rstudio, then saved the resulted variable as Data and upload it into in my directory on the server, after this the file is available in the Files pane (in the lower right quadrant) it also includes an Upload button that does this.

```
#function on my own machine Studio
library(Rfacebook)
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="xxxxxxxxxx", app_secret="yyyyyy")
save(APIKey, file="fb_oauth.RData")
```

-> then upload the file into the server (same Studio Server directory)
-> and download it on the files pane in Studio server.